# Ссылки на аудио в VK

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть страница со списком аудиозаписей в ВКонтакте. Например, вот её кусочек:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
К сожалению, ВК с середины декабря закрыл доступ к работе с аудио, а использовать обходные пути не хочется, ведь это мне и не совсем нужно.
В чём заключается вопрос:
Мне нужно получить список всех аудиозаписей с открытой страницы в виде `audio<USER_ID>_<AUDIO_ID>`.
Есть расширение vk.opt, которое может делать следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если нажать на "wiki", появится окошко с ID аудиозаписи, как я написал выше.

Только проблема в том, что аудиозаписей может быть и 20, и 100, и 10000, и вручную сделать это не получится. Нужно как-то это автоматизировать. В исходном коде есть все ссылки на аудио без слова "audio", но вычленить их оттуда, например, парсером, будет трудновато.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прилагаю код автоскроллера:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js";
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);

script.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var position = 0;
  var timeStep = 1000; // время между шагами скролла
  var scrollStep = 100; // на сколько пикселей скроллить за раз
  var w = $(window); // просто экономим буковки :)

  var i = setInterval(function() {
    w.scrollTop(position + scrollStep);
    if (w.scrollTop() > position) {
      position = w.scrollTop();
      console.log(position);
    } else {
      clearInterval(i);
      // доскроллили до конца, делаем, что нам надо
    }
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 60px;
  word-break: break-all;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div>Автоскроллер</div>
```

Тут придется "поиграть" параметрами `timeStep` и `scrollStep`, в зависимости от того, сколько у вас записей на странице и насколько быстро они грузятся.

Хотя, если делать уж совсем по уму, то надо перехватывать событие подгрузки порции данных и скроллить после него.

Answer (score 1):

Просто вставьте код в консоль браузера на странице с аудиозаписями.

```
var audios = document.getElementsByClassName('audio_row');

Array.prototype.map.call(audios, function(audio) {
    return audio.dataset.fullId;
});
```

Comment: Надо еще автоскроллер добавить